# DirectShowNet - VideoRenderer VS. VideoRendererDefault

Tags: video-streaming, directshow, directshow.net

**In [DirectShowNet](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/), what is the difference between [VideoRenderer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407349%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and VideoRendererDefault?** I cannot find any documentation on VideoRendererDefault, but it is available in both DirectShowNet and GraphEditPlus.

In my application, if I use Default for certain webcams, they cannot connect the pins properly. In other cases, using Non-Default makes it so that my internal webcams on my laptops display black video when set to the highest resolution. I need to figure out why they are different to try to resolve these issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DirectShow.NET follows native API conventions, see [Video Mixing Renderer Filter 7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> `CLSID_VideoRendererDefault`: Creates the VMR-7 if system resources
>   are available, or else creates the old Video Renderer filter.

Comment: Ah. That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. Now, I'm also looking into the VMR-9 too. :-)